# Buscar http o https con una expresion regular y dentro de esa expression poder colocar una variable PHP

Tags: php, regex

si alguien me pudiera ayudar, no soy muy bueno con expresiones regulares, esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
$variable=www.ejemplo.com/archivo

$url_search='^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?'.$variable;

url_search: Lo uso para buscar y reemplazar dentro de str_replace...

$result=str_replace($url_search, $url_image, $image);
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Me equivoque en la parte de url_search, va asi:   $url_search='^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?'.$variable;

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Podrías por favor explicar que es lo que quieres hacer? Quizá no necesites expresiones regulares. No hay por qué usarlas siempre, depende de la complejidad o no de lo que se quiere solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

No me queda muy claro si cuando encuentras www.ejemplo.com/archivo, quieres remplazar todo ese trozo, incluído el nombre del dominio, o solamente "/archivo".

Te voy a presentar una posible solución basándome en el primer supuesto. Cualquier cosa ya me dices:

```
<?php

// Para la prueba
$url_image = 'https://www.ejemplo.com/archivo';
$image = 'www.foo.com/bar';


// Script
$variable='www.ejemplo.com/archivo';

$url_search='#^(https?://)'.preg_quote($variable, '#').'#i';

$result=preg_replace($url_search, '$1'.$image, $url_image);

print $result . "\n";
```

Cambios realizados:

1. Lo más importante, a la hora de incorporar la variable en la expresión regular, escaparla con preg_quote, ya que la variable puede contener caracteres especiales con significado para una expresión regular (como el punto `.` por ejemplo)
2. He simplificado un poco la captura de http/s haciendo la 's' opcional (`?`)
3. He cambiado los delimitadores de la expresión regular a #, de esta manera no tengo que escapar las barras y queda más legible.
4. Al asignar el valor a `$variable` hay que encapsular el string con comillas y terminar la instrucción con `;`
5. En str_replace tenías el segundo y tercer parámetro girados. El segundo es la expresión de reemplazo y el tercero es el string donde realizar las sustituciones.